# Should we reject edits to off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, editing

As has beed discussed in [Considerations for editing and approving edits for closed posts](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/considerations-for-editing-and-approving-edits-for-closed-posts), editing off-topic posts to improve them is counterproductive.

Recently I've been reviewing this edit:
https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52417

This question isn't about aviation or anything related at all - it doesn't belong on the site in any way. At the time it was flagged, but not closed. Editing it doesn't really add value, as it's just going to be closed/deleted. The edit was an improvement, but 0 times N is still 0.

As it happens, the edit got approved, which put the question [back into the review queue](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/52425).

So, to the community: should we approve or reject edits to non-salvageable questions?

What should be the reason given for rejections? I used "harmful", which looks too harsh, but it's the only option with an explanation field attached. Possibly it should even be a separate rejection reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edits to closed questions that do not make the question more likely to be re-opened should not be accepted.

Accepting them only increases the noise, both on the main page and in the reopen queue.